# Hibernate Validator and Jackson: Using the @JsonProperty value as the ConstraintViolation PropertyPath?

Tags: jackson, bean-validation, hibernate-validator

Say I have a simple POJO like below annotated with Jackson 2.1 and Hibernate Validator 4.3.1 annotations:

```
final public class Person {
  @JsonProperty("nm")
  @NotNull
  final public String name;

  public Person(String name) {
      this.name = name;
  }
}
```

And I send JSON like such to a web service:

```
{"name": null}
```

Hibernate when it reports the ConstraintViolation uses the class member identifier "name" instead of the JsonProperty annotation value. Does anyone know if it is possible to make the Hibernate Validator look at the annotation of the class and use that value instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that's not possible. Hibernate Validator 5 (Bean Validation 1.1) has the notion of `ParameterNameProvider`s which return the names to reported in case method parameter constraints are violated but there is nothing comparable for property constraints.

Comment: I've filed issue [HV-823](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HV-823) for supporting this use case in Hibernate Validator.

Comment: Bummer! But also Thank you for opening a feature request.

Comment: This is now supported by Hibernate Validator. Documentation: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#section-property-node-name-provider

Answer (score 8):

Unfortunately there is no easy way to do it. But here are some insights that can help you:

### Parsing constraint violations

From the [`ConstraintViolationException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/validation/ConstraintViolationException.html), you can get a set of [`ConstraintViolation`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/validation/ConstraintViolation.html), that exposes the constraint violation context:

- [`ConstraintViolation#getLeafBean()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/validation/ConstraintViolation.html#getLeafBean--): If it is a bean constraint, this method returns the bean instance in which the constraint is applied to.
- [`ConstraintViolation#getPropertyPath()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/validation/ConstraintViolation.html#getPropertyPath--): Returns the path to the invalid property.

From the property path, you can get the leaf node:

```java
Path propertyPath = constraintViolation.getPropertyPath();
Optional<Path.Node> leafNodeOptional = 
        StreamSupport.stream(propertyPath.spliterator(), false).reduce((a, b) -> b);
```

Then check if the type of the node is [`PROPERTY`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/validation/ElementKind.html#PROPERTY) and get its name:

```java
String nodeName = null;

if (leafNodeOptional.isPresent()) {
    Path.Node leafNode = leafNodeOptional.get();
    if (ElementKind.PROPERTY == leafNode.getKind()) {
        nodeName = leafNode.getName();
    }
}
```

### Introspecting a class with Jackson

To get the available JSON properties from the leaf bean class, you can introspect it with Jackson (see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44266188/1426227) and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45839099/1426227) for further details):

```java
Class<?> beanClass = constraintViolation.getLeafBean().getClass();
JavaType javaType = mapper.getTypeFactory().constructType(beanClass);

BeanDescription introspection = mapper.getSerializationConfig().introspect(javaType);
List<BeanPropertyDefinition> properties = introspection.findProperties();
```

Then filter the properties by comparing the leaf node name with the [`Field`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html) name from the [`BeanPropertyDefinition`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/introspect/BeanPropertyDefinition.html):

```java
Optional<String> jsonProperty = properties.stream()
        .filter(property -> nodeName.equals(property.getField().getName()))
        .map(BeanPropertyDefinition::getName)
        .findFirst();
```

### Using JAX-RS?

With JAX-RS (if you are using it), you can define an [`ExceptionMapper`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/ext/ExceptionMapper.html) to handle [`ConstraintViolationException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/validation/ConstraintViolationException.html)s:

```java
@Provider
public class ConstraintViolationExceptionMapper 
                 implements ExceptionMapper<ConstraintViolationException> {

    @Override
    public Response toResponse(ConstraintViolationException exception) {
        ...
    }
}
```

To use the [`ObjectMapper`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html) in your [`ExceptionMapper`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/ext/ExceptionMapper.html), you could provide a [`ContextResolver<T>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/ext/ContextResolver.html) for it:

```java
@Provider
public class ObjectMapperContextResolver implements ContextResolver<ObjectMapper> {

    private final ObjectMapper mapper;

    public ObjectMapperContextResolver() {
        mapper = createObjectMapper();
    }

    @Override
    public ObjectMapper getContext(Class<?> type) {
        return mapper;
    }

    private ObjectMapper createObjectMapper() {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT, true);
        mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
        mapper.disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS);
        return mapper;
    }
}
```

Inject the [`Providers`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/ext/Providers.html) interface in your [`ExceptionMapper`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/ext/ExceptionMapper.html):

```java
@Context
private Providers providers;
```

Lookup for your [`ContextResolver<T>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/ext/ContextResolver.html) and then get the [`ObjectMapper`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html) instance:

```java
ContextResolver<ObjectMapper> resolver = 
        providers.getContextResolver(ObjectMapper.class, MediaType.WILDCARD_TYPE);
ObjectMapper mapper = resolver.getContext(ObjectMapper.class);
```

If you are interested in getting `@XxxParam` names, refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44272366/1426227).

Comment: Interesting, unfortunately this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44272366/1426227) does not cover the `@xxxParam` inside an object, e.g. `class SearchParams { @QueryParam("from") @Min(1) Integer fromParam; @QueryParam("to") @Min(2) Integer toParam; }` / `@GET @Path("search") Response search(@Valid @BeanParam SearchParams params) { ...`

Comment: @Brice That's true. It can be addressed _without_ relying on a `ParameterNameProvider`. Check my [`ConstraintViolationExceptionMapper`](https://github.com/cassiomolin/tasks-rest-api/blob/master/src/main/java/com/cassiomolin/example/common/api/exceptionmapper/ConstraintViolationExceptionMapper.java) on GitHub. Improvements are welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

I have raised this [issue](https://github.com/zalando/problem-spring-web/issues/610) as I am using [problem-spring-web](https://github.com/zalando/problem-spring-web) module to do the validation, and that doesn't support bean definition names out of box as hibernate. so I have came up with the below logic to override the `createViolation` of `ConstraintViolationAdviceTrait` and fetch the `JSONProperty` field name for the field and create violations again.

```java
public class CustomBeanValidationAdviceTrait implements ValidationAdviceTrait {

    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    public CustomBeanValidationAdviceTrait(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
        this.objectMapper = objectMapper;
    }


 @Override
    public Violation createViolation(ConstraintViolation violation) {
        String propertyName = getPropertyName(violation.getRootBeanClass(), violation.getPropertyPath().toString());
        return new Violation(this.formatFieldName(propertyName), violation.getMessage());
    }


 private String getPropertyName(Class clazz, String defaultName) {
        JavaType type = objectMapper.constructType(clazz);
        BeanDescription desc = objectMapper.getSerializationConfig().introspect(type);
        return desc.findProperties()
                .stream()
                .filter(prop -> prop.getInternalName().equals(defaultName))
                .map(BeanPropertyDefinition::getName)
                .findFirst()
                .orElse(defaultName);
    }
```