# Using Jackson, how can a list of known JSON properties be obtained for any arbitrary pojo class?

Tags: java, json, jackson

Ideally, it would look much like this:

```
List<String> props = objectMapper.getKnownProperties(MyPojo.class);
```

Alas, there is no such method. An approach that would generally work is to explicitly set Include.ALWAYS as the ObjectMapper's default, instantiate an instance of the class reflectively, convert it to a map, and examine the keyset. However, classes can still override the ObjectMapper's include behavior given annotations.

Is there a more elegant approach? At the very least, is there a way to override class annotations using the object mapper?

**Edit:**
Just to clarify, these pojos/javabeans/DTOs are designed for use with Jackson and are already rigged with annotations to result in specific serialization behavior. It just so happens that I need to dynamically know what I might end up with up-front, ideally without duplicating the information already available to jackson. That said, if another framework offers this functionality, I'd be curious to know. :)

Comment: What are you trying to do, exactly? Maybe there's a better tool for the job.

Comment: Have you tried Gson? Then you don't need to know all the properties in order to convert to and from json.

Comment: Specifically, I'm developing a small rest api framework that allows html clients to sort/search based on any json property that corresponds to a singular attribute of the JPA data model. In order to properly construct the query up-front, I need this information to determine the valid possibilities.

Answer (score 7):

With Jackson, you can introspect a class and get the available JSON properties using:

```java
// Construct a Jackson JavaType for your class
JavaType javaType = mapper.getTypeFactory().constructType(MyDto.class);

// Introspect the given type
BeanDescription beanDescription = mapper.getSerializationConfig().introspect(javaType);

// Find properties
List<BeanPropertyDefinition> properties = beanDescription.findProperties();
```

If you have [`@JsonIgnoreProperties`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonIgnoreProperties.html) class level annotations, check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45839099/1426227).

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your exact needs, `JsonFilter` could also work (f.ex see http://www.cowtowncoder.com/blog/archives/2011/09/entry_461.html).

And for more advanced cases, `BeanSerializerModifier` does give you access to actual list of `BeanPropertyWriter`s, which represent individual properties POJO has. From that, you could write a wrapper that enables/disables output dynamically.
Or perhaps you can even combine approaches: modifier to get list of possible property names; then `FilterProvider` to dynamically add filter. Benefit of this would be that it is a very efficient way of implementing filtering.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to ignore all annotations by using a dummy AnnotationIntrospector:

```
objectMapper.setAnnotationIntrospector(new AnnotationIntrospector(){
    @Override public Version version() {
        return Version.unknownVersion();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the breadcrumb. I wouldn't want to ignore all annotations (the effect of `@JsonProperty` and `@JsonIgnore` is pretty fundamental), but ignoring `@JsonInclude` ensures that all potential attributes are serialized. It looks like `AnnotationIntrospector.findSerializationInclusion()` is the thing to override (or perhaps proxy).

Comment: To suppress specific annotations, you can subclass `JacksonAnnotationIntrospector`, override methods that handle relevant annotations.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could use [Jackson's JSON Schema module](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-jsonSchema) to generate a schema for a class, then inspect the schema.