# Serialize Java objects as JSON parallel arrays

Tags: java, json, jackson

In Java, is there a nice way of serializing a collection of objects as a single JSON object of parallel arrays?

For example, given a Collection of type Person

```java
class Person {
  String firstName;
  String lastName;
  int age;
}
```

I would want to produce the following JSON:

```json
{
  "firstName": ["Allison", "Stanley", "Adrian"],
  "lastName": ["Smith", "Williams", "Davis"],
  "age": [23, 17, 42]
}
```

I'd prefer to use [jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) if possible, but all suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You really shouldn't be doing that. Parallel arrays are an anti-pattern.

If you insist (people will hate you), create a class for it and convert the data before generating JSON.

```java
class PersonList {
  List<String> firstName;
  List<String> lastName;
  List<Integer> age;

  PersonList(List<Person> persons) {
    for (Person p : persons)
      add(p);
  }

  void add(Person p) {
    firstName.add(p.getFirstName());
    lastName.add(p.getLastName());
    age.add(p.getAge());
  }
}
```

```java
List<Person> persons = ...

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.writeValue(..., new PersonList(persons));
```

Comment: Thanks. I agree about it being an anti-pattern. Unfortunately it's a business requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I was hoping to find an option that didn't require a new `PersonList` class. One that could take advantage of all of the [introspection logic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45839099/11854106) built into Jackson and identify the properties of `Person` to generate the JSON lists for me.

I'm not seeing anything like that, so extending from the [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67117099/11854106) by [Andreas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5221149/andreas), I'm using Guava's `Lists.transform()` to create the property lists as views of the original, without duplicating the data.

```java
class PersonList {
  List<String> firstName;
  List<String> lastName;
  List<Integer> age;

  public PersonList(List<Person> people) {
    this.firstName = Lists.transform(people, Person::getFirstName);
    this.lastName = Lists.transform(people, Person::getLastName);
    this.age = Lists.transform(people, Person::getAge);
  }

  // getters...
}
```