# How to get the list of properties of a class as Jackson views it (@JsonViews)?

Tags: java, properties, jackson, fasterxml

Given the following class below, how do I get a list of properties as Jackson views it (conforming to @JsonViews)

```java
public class MyDto {

    @JsonView(A.class)
    private int intValue1;

    @JsonView(B.class)
    private int intValue2;

    @JsonView({A.class, B.class})
    private int intValue3;

    // standard setters and getters are not shown
}
```

I have tried following links with no solution:

- [How to get the list of properties of a class as Jackson views it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45834654/how-to-get-the-list-of-properties-of-a-class-as-jackson-views-it)

Answer (score 0):

You should be setting the writer of `ObjectMapper` to use appropriate view when serializing:

```java
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();//

MyDto dto = new MyDto(1, 2, 3);

String viewA = mapper.writerWithView(A.class).writeValueAsString(dto);
String viewB = mapper.writerWithView(B.class).writeValueAsString(dto);

System.out.println("viewA: " + viewA);  
System.out.println("viewB: " + viewB);
```

Output:

```java
viewA: {"intValue1":1,"intValue3":3}
viewB: {"intValue2":2,"intValue3":3}
```

Comment: yes this is for serializing to String. But to clarify, Im looking for a List of properties. Something like
```
List<BeanPropertyDefinition> properties = beanDescription.findProperties();
```