# How to print only the header into a string in Jackson CSVMapper

Tags: java, csv, jackson, jackson-dataformat-csv

I am using Jackson CSVMapper to read a tab separated text file into a list of java objects, and write it back into another tab separated text file. My class looks like this:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@NoArgsConstructor
@JsonPropertyOrder({
    "Id",
    "Name",
    "Address 1",
    "Address 2"})
public class InputSchema {
    @JsonProperty("Id")private String id;
    @JsonProperty("Name") private String name;
    @JsonProperty("Address 1") private String address1;
    @JsonProperty("Address 2") private String address2;
}
```

Parser code:

```
public List<InputSchema> parseAddresses(String fileContent) throws IOException {
    List<InputSchema> inputAddresses = new ArrayList<>();
    InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(fileContent.getBytes());
    MappingIterator<InputSchema> iterator = getInputSchemaMappingIterator(inputStream);

        while (iterator.hasNextValue()) {
            InputSchema inputAddress = iterator.nextValue();
            log.info(inputAddress.toString());
            inputAddresses.add(inputAddress);
        }

    return inputAddresses;
}

private MappingIterator<InputSchema> getInputSchemaMappingIterator(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
    CsvMapper mapper = new CsvMapper();
    mapper.configure(CsvParser.Feature.FAIL_ON_MISSING_COLUMNS, true);
    mapper.configure(CsvParser.Feature.TRIM_SPACES, true);
    CsvSchema schema = mapper.schemaFor(InputSchema.class)
                        .withColumnSeparator('\t')
                        .withHeader()
                        .withStrictHeaders(true);

    ObjectReader reader = mapper.readerFor(InputSchema.class).with(schema);
    MappingIterator<InputSchema> iterator = reader.readValues(inputStream);

    return iterator;
}
```

Writer code:

```
private String toTxt(List<InputSchema> inputAddresses) throws JsonProcessingException {
    CsvMapper mapper = new CsvMapper();
    CsvSchema schema = mapper.schemaFor(InputSchema.class)
        .withColumnSeparator('\t')
        .withLineSeparator("\n")
        .withHeader()
        .withoutQuoteChar();

    return mapper.writer(schema).writeValueAsString(inputAddresses);
}
```

I want to extract just the header irrespective of the data.
So,

```
String header = extractHeader();
```

should return

```
"Id\tName\tAddress 1\tAddress 2"
```

How can I do it?

Thanks!

Comment: can you show the `CSVMapper` code?

Comment: @Deadpool added, please take a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following worked:

```
    public static String displayHeader() {
    CsvMapper mapper = new CsvMapper();

    JavaType javaType = mapper.getTypeFactory().constructType(InputSchema.class);
    BeanDescription beanDescription = mapper.getSerializationConfig().introspect(javaType);
    List<BeanPropertyDefinition> properties = beanDescription.findProperties();

    List<String> columnNames = properties.stream()
        .map(e -> e.getName())
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
    String header = String.join("\t", columnNames);

    return header;
}
```

reference: [@cassiomolin 's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18951789/using-jackson-how-can-a-list-of-known-json-properties-be-obtained-for-any-arbit?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 1):

this works for me.

```java
    public String extractHeader(CsvSchema schema) throws JsonProcessingException {
        CsvSchema headerSchema = schema.withHeader();
        return new CsvMapper().writer(headerSchema).writeValueAsString(null);
    }
```

Comment: This is a much cleaner solution. Thank you.