# Can I change the property path in a ConstraintValidator for Method arguments?

Tags: java, hibernate, bean-validation, jersey-2.0

If you are familiar with the Bean Validation Framework you know that you cannot get the name of a method argument. So if you do a @NotNull constraint on the first argument of a method and the validation fails the getPropertyPath will be something like "arg1".

I would like to create my own version of @NotNull that can take a value e.g. @NamedNotNull( "emailAddress" ). But I can't figure out how to override the #getPropertyPath in my Validator? Is there any way to do this or am I stuck with "arg1" or "arg2", etc.

**EDIT**

Based on the answer I received I was able to come up with the following implementation that allows me to take the value from my @QueryParam or @PathParam annotations and use those as the property path for Bean Validation annotations like @NotNull.

For Jersey you need to create the following class. Note the implementation of DefaultParameterNameProvider:

```
public class ValidationConfigurationContextResolver implements ContextResolver<ValidationConfig> {
    @Override
    public ValidationConfig getContext( final Class<?> type ) {
        final ValidationConfig config = new ValidationConfig();
        config.parameterNameProvider( new RestAnnotationParameterNameProvider() );
        return config;
    }

    static class RestAnnotationParameterNameProvider extends DefaultParameterNameProvider {

        @Override
        public List<String> getParameterNames( Method method ) {
            Annotation[][] annotationsByParam = method.getParameterAnnotations();
            List<String> names = new ArrayList<>( annotationsByParam.length );
            for ( Annotation[] annotations : annotationsByParam ) {
                String name = getParamName( annotations );
                if ( name == null )
                    name = "arg" + ( names.size() + 1 );

                names.add( name );
            }

            return names;
        }

        private static String getParamName( Annotation[] annotations ) {
            for ( Annotation annotation : annotations ) {
                if ( annotation.annotationType() == QueryParam.class ) {
                    return QueryParam.class.cast( annotation ).value();
                }
                else if ( annotation.annotationType() == PathParam.class ) {
                    return PathParam.class.cast( annotation ).value();
                }
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your RestConfig you need to add the following line:

```
register( ValidationConfigurationContextResolver.class );
```

That's it. Now your ConstraintValidationExceptions will contain the name of the QueryParam or PathParam they are annotated with. For example:

```
 public void getUser( 
     @NotNull @QueryParam( "emailAddress" ) String emailAddress,
     @NotNull @QueryParam( "password" ) String password ) 
 { ... }
```

Comment: what if one doesn't use Jersey?

Comment: Very useful, thanks. I added a little refinement:
`if (name == null) name = "payload[" + parameterTypes[index].getSimpleName() + "]";`
instead of `"arg<n>"`.
This provides the type of the payload, the parameter without the inspected annotations in the Rest method. This gives `"path": "SomeResource.testValidation.payload[PayloadDto].attributes"` when validating the fields of the payload DTO (and the type of the payload if it is missing entirely and having the @NotNull annotation).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Bean Validation 1.1 introduced the [`ParameterNameProvider`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/validation/ParameterNameProvider.html) interface for providing names for method and constructor parameters when creating constraint violation objects.

---

Hibernate Validator 5.2 introduced the [`ReflectionParameterNameProvider`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/5.2/api/org/hibernate/validator/parameternameprovider/ReflectionParameterNameProvider.html) class, a [`ParameterNameProvider`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/validation/ParameterNameProvider.html) implementation that uses reflection to get the actual parameter names (to work properly, it requires the classes to be compiled with the `-parameters` compiler argument):

```java
/**
 * Uses Java 8 reflection to get the parameter names.
 * <p>
 * <p>For this provider to return the actual parameter names, classes must be compiled with the '-parameters' compiler
 * argument. Otherwise, the JDK will return synthetic names in the form {@code arg0}, {@code arg1}, etc.</p>
 * <p>
 * <p>See also <a href="http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/118">JEP 118</a></p>
 *
 * @author Khalid Alqinyah
 * @since 5.2
 */
public class ReflectionParameterNameProvider implements ParameterNameProvider {

    @Override
    public List<String> getParameterNames(Constructor<?> constructor) {
        return getParameterNames(constructor.getParameters());
    }

    @Override
    public List<String> getParameterNames(Method method) {
        return getParameterNames(method.getParameters());
    }

    private List<String> getParameterNames(Parameter[] parameters) {

        List<String> parameterNames = newArrayList();
        for (Parameter parameter : parameters) {
            // If '-parameters' is used at compile time, actual names will be returned. Otherwise, it will be arg0, arg1...
            parameterNames.add(parameter.getName());
        }

        return parameterNames;
    }
}
```

---

Dropwizard extends it and add support to JAX-RS `@XxxParam` annotations with the [`JerseyParameterNameProvider`](http://www.dropwizard.io/1.1.0/dropwizard-jersey/apidocs/io/dropwizard/jersey/validation/JerseyParameterNameProvider.html) that should work with other JAX-RS implementations too:

```java
/**
 * Adds jersey support to parameter name discovery in hibernate validator.
 * <p>
 * <p>This provider will behave like the hibernate-provided {@link ReflectionParameterNameProvider} except when a
 * method parameter is annotated with a jersey parameter annotation, like {@link QueryParam}. If a jersey parameter
 * annotation is present the value of the annotation is used as the parameter name.</p>
 */
public class JerseyParameterNameProvider extends ReflectionParameterNameProvider {

    @Override
    public List<String> getParameterNames(Method method) {
        Parameter[] parameters = method.getParameters();
        Annotation[][] parameterAnnotations = method.getParameterAnnotations();
        List<String> names = new ArrayList<>(parameterAnnotations.length);
        for (int i = 0; i < parameterAnnotations.length; i++) {
            Annotation[] annotations = parameterAnnotations[i];
            String name = getParameterNameFromAnnotations(annotations).orElse(parameters[i].getName());
            names.add(name);
        }
        return names;
    }

    /**
     * Derives member's name and type from it's annotations
     */
    public static Optional<String> getParameterNameFromAnnotations(Annotation[] memberAnnotations) {

        for (Annotation a : memberAnnotations) {
            if (a instanceof QueryParam) {
                return Optional.of("query param " + ((QueryParam) a).value());
            } else if (a instanceof PathParam) {
                return Optional.of("path param " + ((PathParam) a).value());
            } else if (a instanceof HeaderParam) {
                return Optional.of("header " + ((HeaderParam) a).value());
            } else if (a instanceof CookieParam) {
                return Optional.of("cookie " + ((CookieParam) a).value());
            } else if (a instanceof FormParam) {
                return Optional.of("form field " + ((FormParam) a).value());
            } else if (a instanceof Context) {
                return Optional.of("context");
            } else if (a instanceof MatrixParam) {
                return Optional.of("matrix param " + ((MatrixParam) a).value());
            }
        }

        return Optional.empty();
    }
}
```

If you don't use Dropwizard, you can use the above code to create your own implementation.

---

Customization of the [`Validator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/validation/Validator.html) used in validation of Jersey resource classes/methods can be done using [`ValidationConfig`](https://jersey.github.io/apidocs/latest/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/server/validation/ValidationConfig.html) class and exposing it via [`ContextResolver<T>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/ext/ContextResolver.html) mechanism:

```java
public class ValidationConfigurationContextResolver 
        implements ContextResolver<ValidationConfig> {

    @Override
    public ValidationConfig getContext(final Class<?> type) {
        ValidationConfig config = new ValidationConfig();
        config.parameterNameProvider(new CustomParameterNameProvider());
        return config;
    }
}
```

Then register the `ValidationConfigurationContextResolver` in `ResourceConfig`.

Refer to the [Jersey documentation about Bean Validation support](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/bean-validation.html) for more details.

Comment: Thanks! `JerseyParameterNameProvider` is what I'm looking for! It is a good example of how one can implement annotation-based resolver for any framework.

Answer (score 11):

> If you are familiar with the Bean Validation Framework you know that
>   you cannot get the name of a method argument

That's not quite correct. Bean Validation specifies the concept of a [ParameterNameProvider](http://beanvalidation.org/1.1/spec/#constraintdeclarationvalidationprocess-methodlevelconstraints-definingparameterconstraints-namingparameters) which allows you to provide your own implementation. Hibernate Validator integrates with [ParaNamer](http://paranamer.codehaus.org/) to provide parameter names. See the Validator [online docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#section-paranamer-parameternameprovider) for more information. Once Validator supports Java 8, it will also support the Java 8 parameter naming facility.

IMO, you should give ParaNamer a go.

Comment: Okay, I'm excited to try this. I'm using this with JAX-RS so I can typically get the parameter name from the QueryParam or PathParam annotations! If this works I will definitely select your answer.

Comment: It Works @Hardy! I will edit your response with an example and mark it answered.

Comment: I found this class: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/5.2/api/org/hibernate/validator/parameternameprovider/ParanamerParameterNameProvider.html which might be equivalent to the one mentioned above.

Comment: @robert_difalco Could you please add a brief snippet which solved your problem?