# Jersey bean validation ParameterNameProvider

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs

I was reading the Jersey docs about [bean validation](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/bean-validation.html). The `ParameterNameProvider` example shows how to define parameter names for a method. However, the implementation looks like this will have to be done for each and every method which obviously doesn't scale. The example is basically useless as is.

Is there a smarter way to do this? Couldn't Jersey infer the name from `@QueryParam` or `@PathParam` annotations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the answer in my question here. It should do exactly what you want.

[Can I change the property path in a ConstraintValidator for Method arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22496527/can-i-change-the-property-path-in-a-constraintvalidator-for-method-arguments)

If you copy my code and run it through a debugger you will see that it is only evaluated once for each method for which it is used. Then during normal running of your app the names will not need to be resolved again.

Comment: I have a question: do the name parameters get cached somewhere or does that method get called for each exception?

Comment: It gets cached when the class is first loaded.

Comment: Actually I tested it and it does not. I simply printed a statement with the method name and it gets called as many time as the endpoint throws a validation exception. Adding caching with Guava's `Multimap` was easy though.

Comment: I wonder if it's because of the particular implementation of the `MetaDataProvider`?