# Spring boot - class validation not working on REST API

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson

I have the following REST API:

```
@ResponseBody
    @PostMapping(path = "/configureSegment")
    public ResponseEntity<ResultData> configureSegment(@RequestParam() String segment,
                                                       @RequestBody @Valid CloudSegmentConfig segmentConfig
                                                        )  {
```

CloudSegmentConfig:

```
@JsonProperty(value="txConfig", required = true)
    @NotNull(message="Please provide a valid txConfig")
    TelemetryConfig telemetryConfig;
    @JsonProperty(value="rxConfig")
    ExternalSourcePpdkConfig externalSourcePpdkConfig = new ExternalSourcePpdkConfig(true);
```

TelemetryConfig:

```
public class TelemetryConfig {

    static Gson gson = new Gson();

    @JsonProperty(value="location", required = true)
    @Valid
    @NotNull(message="Please provide a valid location")
    Location location;

    @Valid
    @JsonProperty(value="isEnabled", required = true)
    @NotNull(message="Please provide a valid isEnabled")
    Boolean isEnabled;
```

Location:

```
static public enum Location {
        US("usa"),
        EU("europe"),
        CANADA("canada"),
        ASIA("asia");
        private String name;

        private Location(String s) {
            this.name = s;
        }
        private String getName() {
            return this.name;
        }
    }
```

When I'm trying to send the following JSON:

```
{
    "txConfig": {
        "location": "asdsad"
    }
}
```

The API return empty response 400 bad request, while I expect it to validate the location to be one of the ENUMs of the class. I also expect it to validate the isEnable parameter while it doesn't although I added all possible annotation to it..

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use @Valid annotation on `TelemetryConfig telemetryConfig` and no need to use @Valid on the field of `TelemetryConfig` class.

```
@Valid
TelemetryConfig telemetryConfig;
```

And for enum subset validation you can create a customer validator with annotation and use it.
A good doc about this [Validating a Subset of an Enum](https://www.baeldung.com/javax-validations-enums#subset-validation)

Comment: Thanks! I see that the errors are showing the real class name instead of the Jackson name, e.g `"telemetryConfig.isEnabled: Please provide a valid isEnabled",` instead of `txConfig`, any way to solve that?

Comment: Maybe you are looking some this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41717866/jsr-303-validation-in-spring-controller-and-getting-jsonproperty-name